# How can I stop HTML5 Canvas Ghosting?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I made a small program that:

1. changes the mouse cursor inside the canvas to a black square
2. gives the black square a nice trail that fades away over time (the point of the program)

Here's the code:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

canvas.style.cursor = 'none'; // remove regular cursor inside canvas

function getMousePos(canvas, e) {
  var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {
    x: e.clientX - rect.left,
    y: e.clientY - rect.top
  };
}

function fadeCanvas() {
  ctx.save();
  ctx.globalAlpha = 0.1; // the opacity (i.e. fade) being applied to the canvas on each function re-run
  ctx.fillStyle = "#FFF";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); // area being faded (whole canvas)
  ctx.restore();
  requestAnimationFrame(fadeCanvas); // animate at 60 fps
}
fadeCanvas();

function draw(e) {
  var pos = getMousePos(canvas, e);
  ctx.fillStyle = "black";
  ctx.fillRect(pos.x, pos.y, 8, 8); // the new cursor
}
addEventListener('mousemove', draw, false);
```

Here's a live example: https://jsfiddle.net/L6j71crw/2/

**Problem**

However the trail does not fade away completely, and leaves a ghosting trail.

Q: How can I remove the ghosting trail?

I have tried using clearRect() in different ways, but it just clears the entire animation leaving nothing to display. At best it just removes the trail and only fades the square cursor alone, but it still doesn't make the cursor completely transparent when the fading process is completed. I have tried finding posts about it, but I found nothing that gave a definitive answer and—most importantly—no posts with a working example.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try having a list of positions, this won't leave a ghost trail!

my code:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var Positions = [];
var maxlength = 20;

canvas.style.cursor = 'none'; // remove regular cursor inside canvas

var V2 = function(x, y){this.x = x; this.y = y;};

function getMousePos(canvas, e) {
    // ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
        x: e.clientX - rect.left,
        y: e.clientY - rect.top
    };
}

function fadeCanvas() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    for(var e = 0; e != Positions.length; e++)
    {
        ctx.fillStyle = ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, " + 1 / e + ")";
        ctx.fillRect(Positions[e].x, Positions[e].y, 8, 8);

    }
    if(Positions.length > 1)
        Positions.pop()

    //ctx.save();
    //ctx.globalAlpha = 0.5; // the opacity (i.e. fade) being applied to the canvas on each function re-run
    //ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
    //ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); // area being faded (whole canvas)
    //ctx.restore();
    requestAnimationFrame(fadeCanvas); // animate at 60 fps
}
fadeCanvas();

function draw(e) {
    var pos = getMousePos(canvas, e);
    Positions.unshift(new V2(pos.x, pos.y));
    if(Positions.length > maxlength)
        Positions.pop()
    //ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    //ctx.fillRect(pos.x, pos.y, 8, 8); // the new cursor
}
addEventListener('mousemove', draw, false);
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L6j71crw/9/

Edit: made the cursor constant.

Comment: Aw man, why didn't I think of that! But it seems to have a somewhat different behaviour than mine, dynamically (visually). Why is that? Is it because it doesn't take into account the speed of the cursor?